# How to add dropdown field in admin -> system -> configuration -> catalog tab?

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

Im working on creating module to add extra dropdown field under admin -> system -> configuration -> catalog -> catalog -> Frontend under "Product Listing Sort by" dropdown. How can I add additoinal field there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to configure that in your system.xml:

```
...
<sections>
    <catalog>
        <groups>
            <frontend>
                <fields>
                    <dropdown translate="label comment">
                        <label>Dropdown</label>
                        <comment>Dropdown with global scope.</comment>
                        <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                        <source_model>jr_customconfigexample/system_config_source_dropdown_values</source_model>
                        <sort_order>30</sort_order>
                        <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                        <show_in_website>0</show_in_website>
                        <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
                    </dropdown>
...
```

http://www.bubblecode.net/en/2012/01/30/add-custom-settings-in-magento-admin-panel/

Comment: That link is broken now.

Comment: @Cragmonkey Working link: http://www.bubblecode.net/en/2012/01/30/add-custom-settings-in-magento-admin-panel/